# Delphi TSpeedButton losing glyph when disabled

Tags: delphi, pascal, glyphicons, glyph

I have a TSpeedButton that should have 2 main statuses, one for the pressed status (down) and one when it's up. What i want to achieve is to display an icon of the glyph bitmap also when the button is not pressed and not enabled.

The bitmap contains 3 icons, one for the pressed button, one for the not pressed and one for the not pressed when the control is disabled.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Buttons.TSpeedButton.Glyph)? You can indicate up to four different states, with four icons, as documented.

Comment: @TomBrunberg ok, but it seems to not be managed the down status and disabled in same time. I wanted to map an icon for this type of status: not down and disabled

Comment: Hmmm... But there can be only one state at a time. Simultaneous down and disabled is not implemented (and why would you need `pressed, disabled` or `not pressed, disabled`? You can interpret it as you wish).

Comment: @TomBrunberg i need this diversification because the action of the TSpeedButton is enabled if the user logged in has the permissions. But if a user doesn't have them it would be great that he could see the status of the button, without being able to interact with it.

A user has to be able to see the status of a TSpeedButton (down or up) regardless of the permission that he has..

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
The next sample code consider that you have loaded your icons/Bitmaps inside TimageList .

```
procedure SpeedButton1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
SpeedButton1.Glyph:=nil;
ImageList1.GetBitmap(0,SpeedButton1.Glyph);
End;

procedure SpeedButton1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
SpeedButton1.Glyph:=nil;
ImageList1.GetBitmap(1,SpeedButton1.Glyph);
end;
```

For the Third status you can do the same with SpeedButton1MouseLeave procedure .

```
procedure SpeedButton1MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
if not SpeedButton1.Enabled then
begin
    SpeedButton1.Glyph:=nil;
    ImageList1.GetBitmap(2,SpeedButton1.Glyph);
end;
```